# ¿Cómo creo un programa en C basado en Bubble Sort que solicite ingresar una cantidad de números (mínimo 20) para ordenarlos en forma ascendente?

Tags: c

Programa que implementa el Algoritmo Burbuja para ordenar mínimo 20 números enteros solicitados al usuario.

Esto es lo que llevo del programa, en si funciona pero no he encontrado como hacer que acepte mínimo 20 números.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
 * Función principal
 */
int main()
{
    int  n, j, i, intercambio;
    printf("Ingrese un número  por favor (mínimo 20) \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arreglo[n];
    printf("Ingrese %d números enteros por favor\n", n);
    for (i= 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arreglo[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < n - i- 1; j++)
        { 
            if (arreglo[j] > arreglo[j+1])
            {
                intercambio      = arreglo[j];
                arreglo[j]   = arreglo[j+1];
                arreglo[j+1] = intercambio;
            }
        }
    }
 
    printf("Lista odenada en forma ascendente:\n");
 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arreglo[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un while:

```
do {
    printf("Ingrese un número  por favor (mínimo 20) \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
} while (n < 20);
```

Recuerda que esto es un VLA (array de tamaño variable) y no funciona en todos los compiladores. Así que tal vez prefieras reservar la memoria con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc):

```
int arreglo[n];
```